# Definition of Category in Hungerford’s Abstract Algebra

Tags: category-theory, definition

**Definition:** A category is a class $\mathcal{C}$ of objects (denoted $A, B, C, ...$) together with

(i) a class of disjoint sets, denoted $\text{hom}(A,B)$, one for each pair of objects in $\mathcal{C}$; (an element $f$ of $\text{hom}(A,B)$ is called a morphism from $A$ to $B$ and is denoted $f:A\to B$);

(ii) for each triple $(A,B,C)$ of objects of $\mathcal{C}$ a function $$\circ: \text{hom}(B,C)\times \text{hom}(A,B)\to \text{hom}(A,C)$$ (for morphisms $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$, this function is written $(g,f)\mapsto g\circ f$ and $g\circ f: A\to C$ is called the composite of $f$ and $g$); all subject to the two axioms:

(I) Associativity. If $f:A\to B$ $g:B\to C$, $h:C\to D$ are morphisms of $\mathcal{C}$, then $h\circ (g\circ f)=(h\circ g)\circ f$.

(II) Identity. For each object $B$ of $\mathcal{C}$ there exists a morphism $1_B:B\to B$ such
that for any $f:A\to B$, $g:B\to C$, $$1_B\circ f=f \text{ and } g\circ 1_B=g.$$

---

From [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3051693/861687) post, above definition is of locally small category, because $\text{hom}(A,B)$ is a set.

**Question:** This is my first time seeing definition which don’t feel rigioursly precise. I mean words object and morphism in the definition are not defined at all. I assume object is inherently difficult to define. In naive set theory, set is defined as collection of objects. Do we face similar difficulty in defining object in category as in set?

How morphisms are defined? Set of all morphism from $A$ to $B$ is $\text{hom}(A,B)$ or element of $\text{hom}(A,B)$ is called morphism from $A$ to $B$? That is, which came first $\text{hom}(A,B)$ or morphism from $A$ to $B$.

I think author assumed $\text{hom}(A,B)$ to be set for all $A,B\in \text{ob}(\mathcal{C})$ because in the book there is no definition (or at least not much discussion) of cartesian product of classes and function on classes. Without these notion composition $\circ$ do not make sense.

(i) is saying $\{\text{hom}(A,B)\mid A,B\in \text{ob}(\mathcal{C})\}$ is a class and $\text{hom}(A,B) \cap \text{hom}(C,D)=\emptyset$ if $(A,B)\neq (C,D)$. Am I right?

**Edit:** I find wikipedia definition of category extremely precise and unambiguous. [Category theory](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiF8KOgooGAAxXMV2wGHQXuDSIQFnoECBoQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCategory_theory%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DA%2520class%2520ob(C)%252C%2Cmorphism%2520from%2520a%2520to%2520b%2522.&usg=AOvVaw3PxBBWSYCn4_UiGpecPkWS&opi=89978449) and [Category (mathematics)](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwjyzv7OoYGAAxURTmwGHScNC0sQFnoECBMQAw&url=https%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FCategory%23%3A%7E%3Atext%3DCategory%2520(mathematics)%252C%2520a%2520structure%2CCategorical%2520data%252C%2520in%2520statistics&usg=AOvVaw3rzqolUWn1B7EPGMcoF51h&opi=89978449).

Comment: What do you mean with "object and morphism in the definition are not defined at all"?  They are abstract elements, you just have classes rather than sets because you want the category of sets, the category of groups, etc  Alternatively you can assume Grothendieck universes and then have the category of level-$k$ sets, the category of level-$k$ groups, etc. while still having (level-$k+1$) sets of objects and (level-$k_1$) sets of homomorphisms.

Comment: "I mean words object and morphism in the definition are not defined at all." Classically in geometry, "point" and "line" are not defined at all.   In ZF set theory, "set" and "membership" are not defined at all. They are all what we call "primitive notions" which must be adopted before any discussion can begin.  One can start discussing category theory within the framework of set theory, but one can also just use a framework which simply begins with objects and morphisms.  This is discussed in "Categories for the Working mathematician".

Comment: @rschwieb I agree with your comment and thank you for referring resource.

Comment: @fweth though I’m not familiar with some notion you commented, I will learn those things in future.

Comment: I wouldn't worry too much about foundations when studying category theory, unless you have a strong interest in set theory to begin with.  The Grothendieck universes are just a (strong) axiom telling you that every element lives in a set $U$ which is closed under various operations (like element, powerset, etc.) so it's large enough to carry out set theory.   In particular you have a hierarchy $U_0\in U_1\in U_2\in\dots$. When doing ordinary category theory, you probably won't even touch the third layer, you just have your small sets, groups, etc. and the categories living one layer above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Object" and "morphism" are simply words. The class $\mathcal{C}$ is just a class, containing elements. What those elements "are" is irrelevant. What is the number $1$ made of? We just are calling elements of $\mathcal{C}$ "objects" (of the category) because that is far nicer and more intuitive than just stating 'elements of $\mathcal{C}$' every time.

$\mathrm{hom}(A,B)$ is defined, by your author to be a set. $(i)$ is correct.

Similarly "morphism" is simply a word for an element of a set $\mathrm{hom}(A,B)$. What these elements fundamentally "are" is again irrelevant. The author could have stated this definition without using the words 'object' or 'morphism' just fine.

Comment: Thank you so much for the answer. So is it appropriate to say a category $\mathcal{C}$ is a pair $\mathcal{C}=(\text{ob}(\mathcal{C}), \text{hom}(\mathcal{C}))$, where $\text{ob}(\mathcal{C})$ and $\text{hom}(\mathcal{C})$ are class? For each ordered pair of objects (elements of $\text{ob}(\mathcal{C})$) $(A,B)$, $\exists$ a set (or class) $\text{hom}(A,B)$. Is it okay to write $\text{hom}(\mathcal{C})=\bigcup_{(A,B)} \text{hom}(A,B)$ or $\{\text{hom}(A,B)\mid A,B\in \text{ob}(\mathcal{C})\}$? I don’t known much about class, is union of class make sense?

Comment: @user264745 I am not very qualified to talk about issues of set theory. My main point is that the things you were objecting to (how are ‘object’ and ‘morphism’ actually defined) are not issues. Your author defines $\mathrm{hom}(A,B)$ to be a set, though, and unions of *sets* are ok.

Comment: Also while many people do understand how to rigorously handle the size issues in category theory, many textbooks involving category theory don’t go there and you will generally find this sort of thing swept under the rug. I got used to just working with categories and never had to learn about the set-theoretic troubles